# How to set TimeOut for complete Observer in RXjava - Android?

Tags: android, timeout, rx-java2

I have many request merged in Observable, and I need a Timeout **Not for every emission** but for **complete observable** in RXjava. Is it Possible??

```
            Observable
            .merge(listOfObservables).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Response>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Response response) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                  
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                  
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `takeUntil` with a delayed `error`:

```java
Observable
.merge(listOfObservables)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.takeUntil(Observable.error(new TimeoutException()).delay(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES, true))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: It relays your sequence of items until the given other sequence, in this case a delayed error signal of `TimeoutException`, happens. This stops the merge and your `onError` will be called.

Comment: It means an Error observable starts running parallel to my merged observables, if my merged observables not completed within 5 minutes takeUnitl will throw error and ignore remaining observables right??

Comment: Thanks, its working, i learned a new Logic in RxJava Today